# Extracting Visual Event 2 output into script

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, perl

In the Visual Event description, it says that it extracts "which elements have events attached to them". I can confirm this by running the bookmarklet and seeing all the colour highlights.

I would like to extract this information without the fancy presentation so that I can play around with it into a script (Ruby/Python/Perl). In other words, I would like to get a list of the divs (and their info ideally) from Visual Event.

Is there any way to do this without digging through the code on GitHub? Not to say that I'm not willing to do this, I was just wondering if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish this very oddly specific task without digging through the code, although this isn't as hard as it seems considering it's quite legible and easy to build on your own system, even if you don't have any previous experience with JavaScript.