# Use Selenium to find all "hoverable" elements on a webpage

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way to use Selenium to find all of the elements that will somehow alter the page whenever they are hovered over? (Such as triggering dropdown menus, tooltip texts, or just simply changing link colors)

The only way that I can think of is taking a baseline screenshot as soon as the page loads and then looping through every single element on the page, mousing over it, and taking another screenshot to compare to the baseline.

EDIT: You are basically looking for all elements that have either a :hover CSS attribute or an onMouseOver javascript event, but since that information is not usually available in the HTML I'm not sure that XPath could help.

Comment: Doesn't Selenium support CSS selectors and is even using Sizzle as fallback?

Comment: Is there a way to use CSS selectors to get all elements that have a :hover selector without knowing the class names of the elements?

Comment: Not that I know of. That would be meta-selector, no?

Can't you add a class `hoverable` or some such?

Comment: I'm trying to make an automated solution that could be run on any webpage, so I am assuming that I am not writing any CSS myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was asking myself [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537132/how-to-find-if-a-dom-element-has-an-event-listener-with-ruby/16574750#16574750) and the conclusion I came to (because I don't understand web development very well) was that my best bet was to modify Visual Event 2 to get all the Javascript events from a web page. It kind of worked and I didn't get any other answers, so I assumed this was the only way. Let me know if you want me to share my code at all, seeing as it was kind of tricky finding where exactly one should modify Visual Event 2 so that you can access their event object.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial solution to your question, as I dont know of a way (other than setting a class name for a hover style) to select based on a css hover property:

```
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://yourdomain.com/page.html");
    List<WebElement> mouseoverElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@onmouseover]"));
    System.out.println("Number of elements with a mouseover attribute: " + mouseoverElements.size());
    for (WebElement e : mouseoverElements) {
      System.out.println(e.getTagName() + ": " + e.toString());
    }
```